# Android, how to update ListView content from external activity?

Tags: java, android

I have a project with 4 classes: 2 activities, 1 adapter and 1 class for simple object. Names of the classes are: **MainActivity**, **AddingItemsActivity**, **ItemAdapter**, **SimpleItem**. In a layout corresponding to the **MainActivity**, there is a list view named **SimpleListView**. **SimpleListView** should contain **SimpleItem** objects. **ItemAdapter** is made to handle **SimpleListView**. Updating, adding items to **SimpleListView** from **MainActivity** is very easy. What I would like to reach is updating, adding items, which appear on the **SimpleListView**, from **AddingItemsActivity** (appear when user come back to the **MainActivity**). Could you tell me what should I do to reach that?

PS: I would like to ask: "how to update **SimpleListView** from **AddingItemsActivity**?" but I have read that it is not proper question, beacuse **SimpleListView** does not exist in **AddingItemsActivity**.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button toAddingActivity = findViewById(R.id.toAddingActivitybutton);
        final ListView simpleItemsListView = findViewById(R.id.SimpleListView);
        final ItemAdapter mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_item_adapter);


        toAddingActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddingItemsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });    
    }
}
```

**AddingItemsActivity**

```
public class AddingItemsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_adding_items);
        Button addItem = findViewById(R.id.AddItembutton);
//        final ListView simpleItemsListView = findViewById(R.id.SimpleListView);
//        final ItemAdapter mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_item_adapter);



        addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                first reflex try, which does not work:

//                SimpleItem item = new SimpleItem("String number 1", "String number 2");
//                mAdapter.add(item);
//                simpleItemsListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**ItemAdapter**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SimpleItem>{
    public  ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }
    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<SimpleItem> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.simple_item_adapter, null);
        }

        SimpleItem  item = getItem(position);

        if (item != null) {
            TextView tv1 = v.findViewById(R.id.adapterTextView1);
            TextView tv2 = v.findViewById(R.id.adapterTextView2);

            tv1.setText(item.getStr1());
            tv2.setText(item.getStr2());
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

**SimpleItem**

```
public class SimpleItem {
    private String str1;
    private String str2;


    public SimpleItem(String s1, String s2)
    {
        str1 = s1;
        str2 = s2;
    }

    public String getStr1()
    {
        return str1;
    }


    public String getStr2()
    {
        return str2;
    }


}
```

Comment: You can `startActivityForResult` from simple items  activity and then after adding items in add items activity, set result with the new item and again in items listing activity,  get the new item in `onActivityResult` and add the item to the list adapter

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `startActivityForResult` to get the result as `SimpleItem` from `AddingItemsActivity`.

   `Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddingItemsActivity.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent,1);`
2. Create a `SimpleItem` in `AddingItemsActivity`, add values to it and use `setResult` to give simple item instance back to MainActivity

   ```
   // inside on click
   SimpleItem item = new SimpleItem("String number 1", "String number 2");
   Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
   returnIntent.putExtra("result", item);
   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
   finish();`
   ```
3. In MainActivity

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

   if (requestCode == 1) {
       if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
           SimpleItem result = (SimpleItem)data.getSerializableExtra("result");
           // add result to the list, used by adapter
           // notify adapter using notifyDataSetChanged
       }
   }
   }//onActivityResult
   ```

Note : add `public class SimpleItem implements Serializable` and seems like you forgot to create and pass list to adapter instances, so simply create it

Comment: I got lost somewhere. In your point 3, in `SimpleItem result=data.getSerializable("result");` I got red-highlited `getSerializable` with `Cannot resolve method 'getSerializable(java.lang.String)`. I guess that application is choosing method from a wrong class. Could you tell me how can I overcome this?

Comment: i forgot the casting as `SimpleItem result= (SimpleItem )data.getSerializable("result");` and don't forget `public class SimpleItem implements Serializable`

Comment: I still obtain `Cannot resolve method 'getSerializable(java.lang.String)'`

Comment: oh my bad, it should be `getSerializableExtra`

Comment: Could you tell me where exactly adapter instance should be created, in which method of MainActivity or outside its methods? And where exactly line `simpleItemsListView.setAdapter(adapterName);` should appear?

Comment: Should `onActivityResult` method finally looks as follows?     `@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                SimpleItem result = (SimpleItem)data.getSerializableExtra("result");
                // add result to the list, used by adapter
                // notify adapter using notifyDataSetChanged
                adapterName.add(result); 
                adapterName.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }
    }`

Comment: `dapter instance should be created` declare it outside oncreate and initialize it inside oncreate and then set it on listview and yes

Answer (score 1):

your adaper is not complete you must override getCount method and set your list.size() to it . then from your MainActivity you mast create a list of simle item and pass it to your adapter .

```
ArrayList<SimpleItem> items=new ArrayList<>();
final ItemAdapter mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_item_adapter,items);
```

then you can put your list to intent and pass it to AddingItemsActivity .

```
Intent intent=new Intent (this,AddingItemsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Key",items);
startActivityForResult(intent,your request code (exam : 14));
```

and in AddingItemsActivity :

```
Bundle bundel=getIntent().getExtras();
ArrayList<SimpleItem> items=(ArrayList<SimpleItem>)bundle.get("Key");
```

change or add items to list and return it to MainActivity :

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("returnedList", item);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

and in onActivityResult of MainActivity :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 14) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
       // ArrayList<SimpleItem> items=(ArrayList<SimpleItem>)data.getSerializableExtra("returnedList");
      items=(ArrayList<SimpleItem>)data.getSerializableExtra("returnedList");
            mAdapter .notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    }
```

And dont forgot implemens your simpleItem class of Serializable

Comment: In the `intent.put("Key",items);` I got `Cannot resolve method 'put(java.lang.String, java.util.ArrayList<com.example.user.applicationfortesting.SimpleItem>)`. In the `ArrayList<SimpleItem> items= (Arraylist)bundle.get("Key");` I got `Cannot resolve symbol 'Arraylist'` and `Cannot resolve symbol 'bundle'`

Comment: dont copy and past ! you must import necessary classes. i edited my answer

Comment: Ok, I see that in your answer there are some typos like `bundel` and then `bundle`, `Arraylist` instead `ArrayList`. In `Intent intent=new Intent (this,AddingItemsActivity.class);` should not it be `getBaseContext()` instead `this`? After all, application stops after clicking `addItem` button.

Comment: about this : > Intent intent=new Intent (this,AddingItemsActivity.class); should not it be getBaseContext() instead this? 
im not sure . whats your error when app closed ?

Comment: Should not it be `returnIntent.putExtra("returnedList", items);` instead `returnIntent.putExtra("returnedList", item);`? After changing that application does not stops. But after clicking `addItem` button, it directs to `MainActivity`. `SimpleListView` is empty.

Comment: yes sorry for typos ! i think you dont override getItem method in your adapter override it and set return items.get(position) for it and create an private list<SimpleItem> in root of your adapter class and name it items and initial it in constractor `this.items=items` and tes again

Comment: `private ArrayList<SimpleItem> items;
    public  ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }
    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<SimpleItem> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return items.size();
    }
` this is how the top of my adapter class looks like. Is it correct? What is more, should not there be called `.setAdapter(...)` somewhere?

Comment: +  `@Override
    public SimpleItem getItem(int position)
    {
        return items.get(position);
    }`

Comment: yes it seems correct, and yes you need to setAdapter for your listview in mainActivity , i suggest you to learn more about custom adapters

Comment: try this and look your listview get any items or not : `ArrayList<SimpleItem> items = new ArrayList<>(); items.add(new SinpleItem("a","b")); ItemAdapter mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_item_adapter,items); simpleItemsListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() ` if its nit work your custom adapter is wrong and you should learn more about it

Comment: In which method of project should I insert that? `onActivityResult`? If indeed, then inserting there this code: `ListView simpleItemsListView = findViewById(R.id.SimpleListView);
        ArrayList<SimpleItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new SimpleItem("a","b"));
        ItemAdapter mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_item_adapter,items);
        simpleItemsListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` 
results in adding element to the ListView. Something similiar I use in `addItem.setOnClickListener`

Comment: no, in my previous comment i wanted to test your adapter and seems it works. i think i made mistake in my answer in  onActivityResult and created new arrayList! change `ArrayList<SimpleItem items=(ArrayList<SimpleItem>)data.getSerializableExtra("returnedList");` to  `items=(ArrayList<SimpleItem>)data.getSerializableExtra("returnedList");`it should work.

Comment: `ArrayList<SimpleItem> items=new ArrayList<>();` is in `onCreate` method, so in `onActivityResult` reference `items` is invisible - `Cannot resolve symbol 'items'`

Comment: `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<SimpleItem> items=new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...`

Comment: Item does not appear on the list. Maybe there is a problem with adapter object? In which method this line `final ItemAdapter mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_item_adapter,items);` should be placed? In which method this adapter should be initialized?

Comment: I have meant: "in which method should this line appear `simpleItemsListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`?" as my second question.

Comment: try my new answer its work you . in this case you can copy and past

Answer (score 1):

try this :

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<SimpleItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
private Button toAddingActivity;
private ListView simpleItemsListView;
private ItemAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toAddingActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toAddingActivitybutton);
    simpleItemsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.SimpleListView);
    mAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.simple_item_adapter, items);
    simpleItemsListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    toAddingActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddingItemsActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 14);
        }
    });
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 14 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
        SimpleItem item=(SimpleItem) bundle.get("reKey");
        items.add(item);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

ItemAdapter :

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SimpleItem>{

private ArrayList<SimpleItem> items =new ArrayList<>();
private Activity activity;
private int layoutResource;
    public ItemAdapter(@NonNull Activity act, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<SimpleItem> data) {
        super(act, resource, data);
        items =data;
        activity=act;
        layoutResource=resource;
    }
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}
@Override
public SimpleItem getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View row=convertView;
    if(row==null || (row.getTag()==null)){

        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        row=inflater.inflate(layoutResource,null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv1=row.findViewById(R.id.adapterTextView1);
        holder.tv2=row.findViewById(R.id.adapterTextView2);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }else {
        holder=(ViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    holder.simpleItem=items.get(position);
    holder.tv1.setText(holder.simpleItem.getStr1());
    holder.tv2.setText(holder.simpleItem.getStr2());

    return row;
}

class ViewHolder{
    TextView tv1;
    TextView tv2;
    SimpleItem simpleItem;
}
```

}

AddingItemsActivity :

```
public class AddingItemsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private Button addItem;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_adding_items);
    addItem=(Button)findViewById(R.id.AddItembutton);

    addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            SimpleItem item = new SimpleItem("String number 1", "String number 2");
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("reKey",item);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

you can change AddingItemsActivity onclick method